# Lightning component error in salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am making a Lightning component and am getting the following error:

> Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.get(): attribute 'newaccount' of component 'markup://c:FirstComponent {6:2223;a}' is not visible to 'markup://c:FirstComponent {6:2223;a}'.

Here's my Component markup:

```
<aura:component controller="NewAccount" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.CreateAccount}" value="{!this}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="newAccount" type="Account" />
    <p class="slds-text-heading--label">Accounts</p>

    <div class="slds-col slds-col--padded slds-p-top--large">


    <ui:inputtext aura:id="name" label="name" value="{!v.newaccount.name}" required="true"/>

    <ui:inputText aura:id="website" label="website" value="{!v.newaccount.website}" />

    <ui:inputtext aura:id="phone" label="phone" value="{!v.newaccount.phone}" />
```

Here's the client-side controller:

```
({
    CreateAccount : function(component, event, helper) {
        var ph = component.find("phone");
        var pc = ph.get("v.value");
        var action = component.get("c.newAccount");
        component.set("v.newaccount", action);
    }
    }
})
```

Comment: Instead of `<aura:attribute name="newAccount" type="Account" />`, use this line - `<aura:attribute name="newAccount" type="Account" default="{'sobject' : 'Account', 'phone' : '', 'website':''}"/>`

Comment: You've also got an extra closing `}` in your controller. Is that a copy/paste typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in LC, everything is case-sensitive.As the error points out there's attribute named `newaccount` is not visible means, there's no aura:attribute with named `newaccount` is present.

Looking at your component markup, there's an aura:attribute named `newAccuont`

So all you need to do is change this line:

```
component.set("v.newaccount",action);
```

To

```
component.set("v.newAccount", action);
```

Also set the default for the above attribute as @SantanuHalder suggested.